# Strange behavior when JavaScript sorts array elements with .map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, react-hooks

I´m using this code:

```
const sortedPlayers = props.scorer.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.nummer > b.nummer) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.nummer < b.nummer) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});
  
         {sortedPlayers.map((player) => {})}
```

And it works as intended, but the strange thing is that this also works:

```
const sortedPlayers = props.scorer.sort((a, b) => {}
{props.scorer.map((player) => {})}
```

Can you please explain this mystery?

Thanks in advance
/Peter

Comment: `Array.prototype.sort` sorts in-place, meaning it mutates the array.

Comment: The `sort` method sorts _in place_. In other words, it mutates the array on which you're calling the method. Generally, you don't want to do that to a prop you pass your component in react, so it would (likely) be better to make a shallow copy of the array `const sortedPlayers =[...props.scorer].sort(...)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply  ASDFGerte & Nick:)  Did not think about that .sort () mutates the array

Answer (score 0):

The `sort` method sorts *in place*. In other words, it mutates the array on which you're calling the method.

Generally, you don't want mutate props you pass your component in React, so it would (likely) be better to make a shallow copy of the array before you sort:

```js
const sortedPlayers = [...props.scorer].sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.nummer > b.nummer) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.nummer < b.nummer) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});
  
sortedPlayers.map((player) => {...});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nick! Did not think about that `.sort()` mutates the array

Comment: @lelkes [it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#return_value)

Comment: The code is working so long it´s only one digit. But it sorts two or more digits incorrectly.
For example: number 15 is sorted between 1 & 2, 111 is sorted between 1 & 15 I tried `let keyA = parseInt(a.text(), 100);
    let keyB = parseInt(b.text(), 100);
    return keyA - keyB;` but get: "TypeError: a.text is not a function